# How to get my D3.js pie charts to transition properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm missing something here and I can't seem to figure it out. I have another pie chart on my page that transitions smooth, but it deals with different data. I keep getting some error of " attribute d: Expected arc flag ('0' or '1'), etc" on the transition. I've console.logged the data I'm using to draw it (the d.(x)Pct) and none of the values are negative. Basically, I'm creating the arc, then setting the endAngle on startup dynamically. Then 10 seconds later, when my update comes in, it should reset the endAngle with the new data. My d.(x)Pct data is all under 1 since 1 is a full circle. What's weird is there are 3 circles, the middle one transitions just fine, but the other 2 disappear and re-appear after the transition is over with. They are updated with the new data, but you don't see the transition considering they disappear. Code is below:

```
// Creates the arc for the pie chart
    var pieArc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .startAngle(0)
                    .innerRadius(0)
                    .outerRadius(100);

    // Draw the circles (carrierServices portion)
    var pieChartsCarrierServices = pieChartsSvg.selectAll(".CarrierServicesPies").data(data);
    pieChartsCarrierServices.enter()
                            .append("path")
                                .attr({
                                    "class": "CarrierServicesPies",
                                    "d": function (d) {
                                        pieArc.endAngle((2 * Math.PI) * d.carrierServicesPct)

                                        return pieArc();
                                    },
                                    "transform": function (d) {
                                        var w = $(this).parent().width();

                                        return "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (yScale(d.id) + 50) + ")" // Radius divided by 2 to center with bar graphs
                                    },
                                    "fill": "white"
                                });
    pieChartsCarrierServices.exit().remove();
    pieChartsCarrierServices.transition().duration(750)
                            .attr({
                                "d": function (d) {
                                    pieArc.endAngle((2 * Math.PI) * d.carrierServicesPct)

                                    return pieArc();
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: @SiddP http://jsbin.com/vakuqaxega/edit?js,console,output

I just came across something too. It only disappears when the difference between the 2 percentages is greater than .25....